# Crear matriculas de carros de forma aleatoria

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Estoy intentando crear una aplicacion que permita crear matriculas de carros de forma aleatoria, como tambien tomar de forma aleatoria una cantidad de vehiculos ya definidos, para luego almacenarlos en un array y poder dar los datos del cliente, nombre + vehiculo aleatorio + matricula aleatoria. Todo lo estoy separando mi Principal Main y luego dentro de una clase hago los llamados, de esta forma:

Esta es mi clase de Matriculas:

```
namespace ProvaCuadro
{
    internal class Matricula
    {
        public static string getMatricula()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Random randomChar = new Random();
                char[] letras = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
                string matriculaRandom = randomChar.Next(10, 99) + "-" + letras[randomChar.Next(26)].ToString() + letras[randomChar.Next(26)].ToString() + "-" + randomChar.Next(10, 99);

                return matriculaRandom;
            }

            return getMatricula().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Y esta este es mi MAIN:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10 + 1; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Viaturas.getViatura()}  {Matricula.getMatricula()}");
    }
}
```

Pero solamente me hace un llamado, es decir, solamente me trae un vehiculo y una matriculas repetida 10 veces, y no quiero eso, quiero que cambie por cada llamado, y me pueda dar carros y matriculas diferentes por cada iteracion.

Resolver este dilema

---

[image: Problema]

Este es el gran problema que estoy teniendo, al momento de llamarlo desde mi clase principal "Program.cs" y hacer o no el ciclo, siempre me traera las mismas, y necesito 10 pero distintas cada una entre si

PROBLEMA RESUELTO:
Parece realmente que se tratara de un problema con la version de Visual Studio, ya que ahora, que coloque que abriera un proyecto nuevo con Aplicativo de Consola, parece funcionar. Sin embargo, ahora tengo un nuevo problema.

PROBLEMA #2:

He conseguido realizar las correcciones, me queda de esta forma, pero ahora quiero almacenar en un array los vehiculos y las matriculas, para luego, asignarle dichos datos a un cliente en particular, para que asi, el vehiculo y la matricula corresponda realmente al cliente. Esto es, porque debo hacer un historico de todos los clientes (los cuales se muestran en la imagen), y despues, crear una ficha de usuario para un solo cliente, el cual, como en este caso, Gustavo Serrano tiene un Seat(Arosa) con su matricula, y yo quiero presentarlos aqui:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí, como tambien, quiero saber que es eso que ahora me aparece debajo de la consola : C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\Mi repositorio de C Sharp\Prueba2C_Projeto\Prueba2C_Projeto\bin\Debug\net6.0\Prueba2C_Projeto.exe (proceso 9264) se cerró con el código 0.] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te faltan detalles, cual es la longitud de la matricula, cuantas letras y numeros puede tener, donde van, etc, aclara mejor tu problema, recuerda que los paises tienen diferentes estandares de matriculas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Creo que hay un error en el bucle for del método estático `getMatricula()`.
No estoy muy familiarizado con la sintaxis de C#, pero creo que el `return matriculaRandom;` podría estar causándote problemas

Comment: @AndresGardiol el codigo en si, no tiene sentido y seguro esta tirando warnings... el for no tiene sentido, no itera sobre nada.

Comment: Si, realmente pensé que era un tema de sintaxis de C#, pero ahora que veo con más detenimiento, la función no tiene ningún tipo de sentido

Answer (score 2):

Tu función `getMatricula()`, dentro del ciclo haces un `return`, luego sales del ciclo y llamas a tu misma funcion recursivamente y creas un bucle erróneo, si te das cuenta en el propio Visual Studio te da el hint que tienes código inaccesible.

Debes de simplemente en tu función `getMatricula()` sin necesidad de hacer bucles, generar el código y luego en tu main, allí hacer tu ciclo las veces que sean necesarias.

```
public static string getMatricula()
{
     string matriculaRandom = String.Empty;

     Random randomChar = new Random();
     char[] letras = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
     matriculaRandom = randomChar.Next(10, 99) + "-" + letras[randomChar.Next(26)].ToString() + letras[randomChar.Next(26)].ToString() + "-" + randomChar.Next(10, 99);

     return matriculaRandom;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando hace el return, ya no sale del ciclo ni sigue ejecutando ese metodo...

Comment: No hay ningún ciclo dentro de getMatricula() en esta respuesta

Comment: Lo digo por tu explicacion del problema...

Comment: Es que sinceramente han varios problemas con el método original, creí que eso era la mejor forma que se entienda. Como tú indicas, en el primer return el ciclo se acaba y nunca accede al otro return, pero por eso lo intenté explicar para que el autor entienda que lo que estaba haciendo en sí tenía 2 problemas  y 1 ya se lo habían explicado en los comentarios

Comment: la respuesta es buena.. solo ese punto puede confundir a alguien que no entienda bien (porque la llamada recursiva no se hace nunca, ese codigo es inaccesible) ;)

Comment: Esta muy buena la respuesta, olvide decir, que el getMatricula() está es en una clase aparte, llamada Matriculas.cs, y quiero traerla (invocarla) a mi Main (Program.cs) y hacer la iteracion 10 veces con matriculas diferentes, como podria hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Si la función `getMatricula` devuelve una matricula aleatoria, no necesitas ningún bucle:

```
public static string getMatricula()
{
    var r = new Random();
    String l = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN0PQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int n1 = r.Next(10, 99);
    int l1 = r.Next(0, l.Length);
    int l2 = r.Next(0, l.Length);
    int n2 = r.Next(10, 99);

    return $"{n1}-{l[l1]}{l[l2]}-{n2}";
}
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine($"Matricula {i + 1}: {getMatricula()}");
}
```

Ten en cuenta que hay letras que no se ponen en las matrículas por ser fácilmente confundibles entre si (por ejemplo `Q` y `O`) o que se pueden confundir con números (por ejemplo `1` `I` o `O` `0`).

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNT8JAEIbP7a8YGw5tEEJ7w4aD4rdAEFRUwmEta91kmTW7W9Q0@9vrFIgfifH0zs7z7szkzUwrU5pXVWEE5jD9MJavUj@TzBgYa5VrtvJL33stnqTIwFhmN6Jrd87tkFGZFZKFke@Rz1szDRp6gPwNJgyXahVGKfWn2y@SUHB41D8@OT07v7i8GgxHnfH1ZHpzeze7f3gMUp@8Ai1gTE7dHvF3G8adfeh2N2NqJH8gIrI94Jjbl2@e/M8x@WM0Mc1toREaQYmxa5VyLuOFqyVZ0BMTR9d5jpy7FNZKLGHIBIbbPOYLYDo3uyCelYawXidoWycl2etBTEWzKcjieX2FRknenmlh@UAgDxvBV5xQCmhC7A6g/J2yC6LNFa6qPgE)</kbd>.

Comment: Estoy mismo usando tu codigo, pero me siguen apareciendo las mismas matriculas, el mismo resultado multiplicado 10 veces, no se que esta sucediendo, el codigo de mi profesor tambien era similar y funcionaba, daba 10 matriculas distintas, pero el mio, a pesar de copiar y pegar, solo da una matricula 10 veces